# Mobile DOM stacking order with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom, mobile

I want to take one DOM element (accordion menu) and put it underneath the content div. I was told in a prior thread to build with the menu on the bottom, but I built it so the sidebar menu is before the content in my markup like so:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
   <div id="sidebar1" class="span3">
   ...
   </div>
        <div id="right" class="span9">
        ...
        </div>
```

I am using javascript to detect width, and it is working... some of the time. Not sure why it isn't consistent. Maybe because of the way i am approaching it.

```
jQuery(window).resize(function(){

    var windowsize = jQuery(window).width();
    if (windowsize < 768) {
        jQuery("#right.span9").insertBefore(jQuery("#sidebar1.span3"));
        } else {
            jQuery("#sidebar1.span3").insertBefore(jQuery("#right.span9"));
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me.

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){

if (jQuery(window).width() < 768) {
    jQuery("#right").insertBefore( "#sidebar1" );
    } else {
        jQuery("#sidebar1").insertBefore( "#right" );
    }
});
```